# Fastest way to lookup pattern matching words in java

Tags: java, string, performance, lookup, trie

Given a dictionary of words somewhere between 100,000-500,000 total words whats the fastest way to lookup a pattern/mask? where '-' is an unkwown letter i.e. s--t- would return salts, salty, scats, scots etc...

Currently using a trie which is great for words which have the initial letters filled but when there's a pattern such as ---st or -tr- the benefit of a trie is entirely lost.

There is essentially an even distribution of words I'm searching which have the first letters filled and those that do not.

Would loading the words into a SQL database make any sense to then use the SQL wildcard search feature? Or what about a hashmap where I just manually search every possible letter combination for the blank letters?

Would appreciate any insight you could give.

Comment: I suppose that you could mirror the dictionary with each word's letters in reversed order.

Comment: That’s a good idea but there are lookups with no leading letters on either side (I should have mentioned that). I will try to implement mirroring for now that will certainly save some time

Comment: It would be a good idea to profile the time savings. Sometimes, even with the best of logic, such things do little or nothing. I think SQL would be a better choice.

Comment: The only thing I can think of to speed up the search is to check the length of the word in the dictionary first, then compare the letters.  Otherwise, you have to go through the entire dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following little method utilizes the [String#matches()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_matches.htm) method along with a dynamically created [Regular Expression](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) which based on what wildcards were supplied in the search criteria string. It will return a String List (`List<String>`) of any words found that match the supplied criteria string.

The word list **file** I run the search criteria string (`"s--t-"`) through (using **BufferedReader(FileReader)**) contains 370,108 words and in general completes the task in about 250 milliseconds or 0.25 seconds (on average).

As for wildcard characters, the most commonly used wildcard characters are the asterisk (*****), which typically represents zero or more characters in a string of characters, and the question mark (**?**), which typically represents any one character. You apparently want to use the hyphen (-) in place of the usual question mark which is okay. The provided method can handle all three wildcard types (*****, **?**, and **-**) within the same criteria string for your specific purpose.

```
public static List<String> searchForWord(String dictionaryFilePath, 
                                         String searchCriteria) {
    // This method ignores letter case!
    List<String> foundList = new ArrayList<>();  // To hold all found words.

    // Convert the supplied criteria string to a Regular Expression 
    // for the String#matches() method located in the 'while' loop.
    String regEx = searchCriteria.replace("?", ".").replace("-", ".").replace("*", ".*?").toLowerCase();

    // 'Try With Resources' use here to auto-close the reader.
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(dictionaryFilePath))) {
        String line = "";
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            line = line.trim().toLowerCase();
            if (line.matches(regEx)) {
                foundList.add(line);  // There's a match...add to the List.
            }
        }
    }
    // catch Exceptions (if any).
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex);
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex);
    }
    return foundList;  // Return the List.
}
```

To use this method:

```
List<String> list = searchForWord("WordFile.txt", "s--t-");
for (String str : list) {
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

Matches found from the Word List I used:

```
saeta    saite    saith    sakti    salta
salts    salty    santa    santo    santy
saute    sauty    scats    scatt    scote
scots    scott    scuta    scute    scuts
scyth    seats    sects    seity    senti
sents    septa    septi    septs    serta
sesti    sexto    sexts    sheth    shita
shits    shote    shots    shott    shute
shuts    sidth    sifts    silts    silty
sinto    sintu    sitta    sixte    sixth
sixty    skate    skats    skete    skite
skits    skyte    slate    slath    slats
slaty    slete    slite    slits    slote
sloth    slots    sluts    smeth    smite
smith    smote    smuts    smyth    snath
snite    snits    snitz    snots    softa
softs    softy    sooth    soots    sooty
sorts    sorty    south    sowte    spate
spath    spats    spete    spite    spits
spitz    spots    sputa    spute    sruti
state    stats    stets    stite    stith
stott    suets    suety    suite    suits
suity    sutta    swath    swati    swats
swith    swots    syftn
```

Comment: this solution worked well. I made it faster by not inserting all words into a single wordlist but rather having a seperate wordList for varying word length's. So there was a list for strings with length 4,5,6 etc.....